# How to View Classpath While Debugging in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, debugging, gwt, classpath, classloader

I'm trying to troubleshoot a GWT-based app I'm writing in Eclipse. It currently uses Spring Framework 3.1.1 and Hibernate 4.1.6 on the back-end side. I'm currently having troubles with the dreaded "javax.validation.ValidationException: Unable to find a default provider" that seems to plague a lot of folks but is caused by different problems. I've tried the various solutions of using different versions of the JSR 303 implementation (e.g. diff. versions of Hibernate Validator) but it doesn't seem to make a difference.

And after debugging, I'm seeing why. Once execution gets to javax.validation.Validation.getValidationProviders():317 (in validation-api-1.0.0.GA), the app (running on an Eclipse internal Jetty server) attempts to read the META-INF/services/javax.validation.spi.ValidationProvider resource from the classpath and comes back empty. I am absolutely certain that the different validator implementations I've put (e.g. hibernate-validator-4.3.0.Final.jar) have that resource and it does contain a value (e.g. org.hibernate.validator.HibernateValidator), but is not appearing to the classloader in question. The way I've included the JAR in the classpath is by adding it to the project's Build Path which seems to add it to the Jetty runtime when I execute the applications.

My question is: Is there a way to view the classpath in Eclipse debug mode visible to a certain classloader? Secondly, does anyone know why the Hibernate Validator's resource is not first and foremost in the classloader that Validation is using?

Answer (score 1):

The webapp classpath is composed by the directory WEB-INF/classes and by all the jars in WEB-INF/lib. If you want a jar to be available at runtime, you must NOT add it to the build path, but to WEB-INF/lib.

Dropping a jar in WebContent/WEB-INF/lib in Eclipse will make it automatically part of the buid path of your webapp, and available at runtime.

Comment: Just a small note: in GWT DevMode, the runtime classpath of the DevMode (which Eclipse initializes from the project's Build Path) is used as a fallback but then a warning is printed in the "Development Mode" view.